# How do I delete a directory tree with pathlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, pathlib

I have a project using `pathlib` and I want to do the equivalent of `shutil.rmtree`.

I thought of doing it with something like:

```
def pathlib_rmtree(folder):
    if folder.exists():
        for file in folder.glob('**/*'):
            if file.is_dir():
                file.rmdir()
            else:
                file.unlink()
        folder.rmdir()
```

but I am not sure whether the `folder.glob('**/*')` is guaranteed to be ordered so that all the subfolders are empty before calling `rmdir`.

So the question is twofold:

1. Is there a better way to recursively delete a directory with `pathlib`?
2. Does `glob` guarantees the order of its result so that all the files are returned before the subfolder they belong to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually this can be done with `iterdir` rather than `glob`:

```
def rmtree(root):

    for p in root.iterdir():
        if p.is_dir():
            rmtree(p)
        else:
            p.unlink()

    root.rmdir()
```

Comment: A minor addition is to add an if root.exists() check.